# How to filter Google Places API for City term

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to filter the Google Places API results for a specific City. The filter has to be made by exclusion, not by sorting. I know I can specify the `location` and `radius` but that's not enough, because that only priorities the search results.

The level of filtering I desire is the same available for `Country`.

My `urlCall` looks like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?components=country:pt&types=address&input=INPUT&language=en-US&key=MY_KEY`

What I'm doing right know is iterating through the JSON result and evaluating if there's a `term` with the city name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Other solution (more performance friendly) is to check if the `city` name is present in the `description` field. But still, not as good as the `country` filtering system.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you match the `administrativeArea` if your goal is to filter our the city?

> The (cities) type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match locality or administrative_area_level_3.

[places API resource](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Comment: Adding `&administrative_area_level_3=CITY` to the link didn't filter any of the results

Comment: Looks like current Web Service only support country filtering.